# UIimage drawInRect not release memory

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiimage

I have the following code that i used to get new UIImage. 
It would be called about hundred times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.arrayImage count]; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage *image = [self.arrayImage objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImage *newImage = [self getNewImage:image];
        // do something
    }
}

[self.arrayImage removeAllObjects];
```

// getNewImage method

```
- (UIImage *)getNewImage:(UIImage *)image {
    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    // do something

    [image drawInRect:rect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

After finishing , i found out that memory is not released.
It takes almost 200MB memory.
Is there something i missing?

Comment: What do you do with `newImage`? Are you testing on a real device? Don't trust the simulator when checking for leaks or reference cycles.

Comment: I don't do anything with newImage . I just use the same code for testing.
I run it on iPhone6 and see memory info on debug navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that why memory is not released.
My app use SDWebimage , the images in self.arrayImage are from SDWebimage.
So just call `[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearMemory]` to release these images.